# FullCalendar show events in week and day view only but not in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar has - "Month|Week|Day" view , I want to remove or hide events from "Month" only but show in "Week" and "Day" views.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it done and i want to share to everyone so it'll help someone else

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if(view.type == 'month') {
      $(element).css("display", "none");
    } else {
      element.attr('title', event.address);
    }
}
```